# Submit foreach as array to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, post

I am needing away to insert data to a database based on an auto generated list from a form.

So I have this that lists out the key and value, but I need to create an array that I can then use a $sql insert to database.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if($value != "") {
            print $key.": ".$value . "<br>";
        }
}
```

So then I have this for $sql insert

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO FDPU ($key) VALUES ('$value')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo $key.'='.$value.'New record created successfully'.'<br />';
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: so put that query code inside your loop. you don't have to build an array, because $_POST is already an array... and note that you're almost certainly vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: I am guessing that you want the SQL to look like `INSERT INTO FDPU ([key1], [key2]...) VALUES ('[value1]', '[value2]'...)`?

Comment: If I put the query code inside the loop it creates a record/row for every value, I need the values to be inserted within the same row. And I will tackle the sql injection attacks.

Comment: Yes @Anders that is the concept I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but something like this should do it:

```
$keys = array();
$values = array();

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if($value != "") {
            $keys[] = $key;
            $values[] = "'" . $value . "'";
        }
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO FDPU (" . implode(',', $keys) . ") VALUES (" . implode(',', $values) . ")";
```

It stores the keys and values of the variables that are not empty, and then put them together using the very handy function [implode](http://php.net/implode).

Comment: That works perfect, thank you. I knew i was close with it, just couldn't get that last part. I have the main form page generated from the columns in database which is automated, and wanted this part to be automated as well. Seriously, thank you so much.